# Tensorboard for DQN - Reinforcement Learning

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I am running a reinforcement learning training script; therefore, the model is trained once per episode:

```
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir= 'thepathIvespecified')      

model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(batch_input_shape=(1, input_dimension)))

model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(parameters["max_products"]))
model.add(Activation('linear'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae'])  

history = model.fit(current_state_input,
                                target_vec.reshape(-1, parameters["max_products"]), 
                                epochs = 1, 
                                verbose = 0,
                                callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

However, it creates one file at every step in the folder.

How can I correctly display Tensorboard?

Comment: What do you see in Tensorboard, currently?